# Coefficients in Hilbert's tenth problem over number rings: do they matter?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computability-theory

Here are two ways to define Hilbert's tenth problem over a ring $R$:

1. Given a polynomial $p \in \mathbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, can one decide whether it has a solution in $R^n$?
2. Given a polynomial $p \in R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, can one decide whether it has a solution in $R^n$?

I am interested in the case where $R$ is the ring of integers of a number field.  In [Bjorn Poonen's survey](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/aws2003.pdf), he explains in §10 that he's talking about (1) but all the papers he cites in Theorem 14.1, including his own, discuss (2) and as far as I can tell don't mention (1).  So that would seem to imply that (1) and (2) are equivalent in this situation, but I can't find this stated anywhere.

**The question:** Is it true that (1) and (2) are equivalent when $R$ is the ring of integers of a number field?  Is there a reference for this?

**Addendum:** A sufficient criterion for Hilbert's tenth problem to be undecidable over $R$ is that $\mathbb Z$ is Diophantine over $R$.  That is, there is a polynomial $P(x,y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ such that for $x \in R$,
\begin{equation} \tag{$*$}\label{thing}
\exists y_1,\ldots,y_n \in R\text{ such that }P(x,y_1,\ldots,y_n)=0 \quad \iff \quad x \in \mathbb Z.
\end{equation}
In fact, every proof of the undecidability of Hilbert's 10th problem over a number ring $R$ uses this idea.  So:

**Effectively equivalent question:** Given a polynomial $P \in R[x,y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ satisfying \eqref{thing}, where $R$ is the ring of integers of a number field, is it always possible to find a polynomial $P \in \mathbb Z[x,y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ (maybe for a different $n$) satisfying \eqref{thing}?

Comment: If the number field is of finite degree, then the answer is: 1 and 2 are equivalent. Just represent all coefficients and variables as linear combinations of the basis.

Comment: Hmm, would you be willing to expand this into an answer?  I see how to turn a polynomial equation over $R$ into a system of polynomial equations over $\mathbb Z$, but if the variables are interpreted in $R$ then the system may have other solutions that don't obviously correspond back to a solution to the original equation.  But maybe I'm just being obtuse.

Comment: A system of polynomial equations over $\Bbb Z$ is equivalent to one equation. If $z$ is a  variable of the original equation, $\alpha,\beta$ is a (integral) basis and you substitute $z=x\alpha+y\beta$, and you find $x,y$, then you find $z=x\alpha+y\beta$.

Comment: Fix $\xi\in R=O_K$ such that $K=\mathbb Q(\xi)$. Then given a system of polynomials $p\in R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, introduce a new variable $z$ for $\xi$, write each $p$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x_1,\dots,x_n,z]$, add to the system the minimal polynomial $f_\xi\in\mathbb Q[z]$ of $\xi$, and multiply each equation by a sufficiently large integer to make it an integer equation. This is solvable over $R$ iff the original system is, as for any $\xi'\in R$ such that $f_\xi(\xi')=0$, there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $R$ such that $\sigma(\xi')=\xi$.

Comment: I see that you defined the problem only for systems consisting of one equation, but this makes no difference. If $K$ is formally real, you can just take the sum of squares of all the polynomials; in general, there will be a polynomial $f\in\mathbb Z[x,y]$ such that $f(x,y)=0\iff x=y=0$ for any $x,y\in K$, and this can be used to combine multiple equations into one.

Comment: Thanks @EmilJeřábek, that answers my question!